How to reach booking.com about my genius level 3 account I can't get into?
I have worked hard to get genius level 3 and spend a lot of money with booking.com. One of the promised perks was personal support. Yet I can't login, suddenly it says my password is wrong, even though it isn't and neither the reset link is working nor login via link.
Is booking.com just looking for excuses to terminate level 3 accounts? How do I even contact them now? There is no contact option unless its about a specific booking.
I feel like an idiot doing all these vacations in such a short time only for my account to be locked without notice only a few months after.

Only way I could see that might work is filling in the Dispute Resolution form and asking them to contact you.  Or maybe create a new separate account and then contact their support.

I know that this is probably very, very unlikely, but are you sure you are trying to log onto booking.com, and not some look alike site that is trying to steal your info?

Leaving aside the possibility of a fake website and/or the L3 Booking.com status itself being useless, this article gives a few contact options, including CEO details.

@Traveller that's probably the best/only answer available for how to contact them
